# Regarding final keyword in the method setName() of Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

Is final a access modifier in java or a non access modifier ?

Is this setName() method of Thread class **public final void setName(string name)** really final ? If yes does it mean that once the thread name is changed then it cant be changed later because of final keyword..?

Or final is not a part of the method setName() ?

Plz guide me with the correct Answer..

Comment: Another good question to read for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351568/java-basics-about-final-keyword

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks alot

Comment: What part of `public final void setName(String name)` don't you understand? What part of `final` don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP I got my answer. If it has marked as final, it cant be overridden. And the predefined methods of Thread Class cant be final and if they were, we cant use it..!

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that there is a difference between:

1. **Making `member variables` as final and**

   - Whenever `variables` of any class are marked as final, it means that they can't be changed later
   - *point to remember*: As @GhostCat pointed out, when marking `member variables` as final, Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value, however, the object it refers to can possibly be  changed. For example consider this `List` object:

     ```
     final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
     list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Invalid  
     list.add(2); //Valid
     ```

     see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750814/2815219) answer for more details.
2. **Marking `method declarations` as final**

   - Whenever any `method` is declared as final, it means that it cant be cannot be overridden by subclasses.
3. **Making `class`es in java as final**

   - Whenever any class is declared as final, it means that it can't subclassed, i.e., that it can't be extended by any other class. (eg, String class)

---

Now since the `setName()` method of `Thread` class is `final` doesn't mean that we can't change the `name` of this `Thread`. Instead, it simply means that this method cannot be overridden by the classes that `extends` this class.

Comment: You could add information about making a class final, too. And maybe point out, that yes, the reference a final variable is pointing too can't be changed; but variable itself can still be "changed" (like: adding / removing elements when that variable is a list).

Comment: @Raman Sahasi Thanks a lot.!

Comment: I've added that information @GhostCat Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your 'point to remember' is back to front. The variable *can't* be changed, but the object it refers to can possibly be mutated. @GhostCat's language is poorly chosen.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry, that was a quick copy paste. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer accordingly.